# How to create auxiliary table in concise way?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create temporary table with some dataset to execute more complicated query to mysql DB.

I see two possible ways to do it.

create table and insert every row:

```
 create temporary table dates  (
     date date not null
 );

 insert into dates values ('2010-01-01');
 insert into dates values ('2010-02-01');
 insert into dates values ('2010-03-01');
```

or create in-place table:

```
select * 
from (
    select '2010-01-01' as date
    union select '2010-02-01' as date
    union select '2010-03-01' as date
) as dates;
```

Is there other more concise way to do such table?

Answer (score 0):

Some like to create permanent aux tables like sequence of numbers or dates and then just reference them in their queries.  Other DB systems allow recursive CTEs which are more concise.

You could write a stored procedure that can loop and create your temporary table more concisely.

Although a bit silly of a suggestion, your provided SQL does not need the "AS Date" except on the first select of the derived table and you should use UNION ALL instead of UNION.